# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: but the files are there...

Tags: python, excel, pandas, file, operating-system

If you do print filename in the for loop #commented below, it gives you all the file names in the directory. yet when I call pd.ExcelFile(filename) it returns that there is no file with the name of : [the first file that ends with '.xlsx' What am I missing? 
p.s: the indentation below is right, the if is under the for in my code, but it doesn't show this way here..

```
for filename in os.listdir('/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files'):
if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
    month = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    day_list = month.sheet_names
    i = 0
    for day in month.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(month, sheet_name=day, skiprows=21)
        df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
        df = df[[df.columns[0], df.columns[4], df.columns[8]]]
        df = df.iloc[1:16]
        df['Date'] = day
        df = df.set_index('Date')
        day_list[i] = df
        i += 1

    month_frame = day_list[0]
    x = 1
    while x < len(day_list):
        month_frame = pd.concat([month_frame, day_list[x]])
        x += 1

    print filename + ' created the following dataframe: \n'
    print month_frame  # month_frame is the combination of the all the sheets inside the file in one dataframe !
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - reading files from directory file not found in subdirectory (which is there)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580716/python-reading-files-from-directory-file-not-found-in-subdirectory-which-is-t)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your work directory is not the same as the directory you are listing. Since you know the absolute path of the directory, the easiest solution is to add `os.chdir('/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files')` to the top of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Your "if" statement must be inside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are trying to open a relative file-path from a different directory than the one you are listing. Rather than using `os` it is probably better to use a higher level interface like [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import pathlib
for file_name in pathlib.Path("/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files").glob("*.xslx"):
    # this produces full paths for you to use
```

`pathlib` was added in Python 3.4 so if you are using an older version of python, your best bet would be to use the much older [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module, which functions similarly:

```
import glob
for file_name in glob.glob("/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files/*.xslx"):
    # this also produces full paths for you to use
```

If for some reason you really need to use the low-level `os` interface, the best way to solve this is by making use of the [`dir_fd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) optional argument to `open`:

```
# open the target directory
dir_fd = os.open("/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files", os.O_RDONLY)
try:
    # pass the open file descriptor to the os.listdir method
    for file_name in os.listdir(dir_fd):
        # you could replace this with fnmatch.fnmatch
        if file_name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            # use the open directory fd as the `dir_fd` argument
            # this opens file_name relative to your target directory
            with os.fdopen(os.open(file_name, os.O_RDONLY, dir_fd=dir_fd)) as file_:
                # do excel bits here
finally:
    # close the directory
    os.close(dir_fd)
```

While you could accomplish this fix by changing directories at the top of your script (as suggested by another answer), this has the side-effect of changing the current working directory of your process which is often undesirable and may have negative consequences. To make this work without side-effects requires you to `chdir` back to the original directory:

```
# store cwd
original_cwd = os.getcwd()
try:
    os.chdir("/Users/ramikhoury/PycharmProjects/R/excel_files")
    # do your listdir, etc
finally:
    os.chdir(original_cwd)
```

Note that this introduces a race condition into your code, as `original_cwd` may be removed or the access controls for that directory might be changed such that you cannot `chdir` back to it, which is precisely why `dir_fd` exists.

`dir_fd` was added in Python 3.3, so if you are using an older version of Python I would recommend just using `glob` rather than the `chdir` solution.

For more on dir_fd see [this very helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852542/5458214).