# Support for POSIX openat functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix

There is a [patch](https://bugs.python.org/issue4761) to add support for the POSIX [`openat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) functions (and other `*at` functions like [`fstatat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html)) to the python standard library that is marked as `closed` with resolution `fixed`, but the `os`, `posix` and `platform` modules do not currently include any of these methods.

These methods are the standard way of solving problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851986/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-files-are-there) in `C` and other languages efficiently and without race conditions.

Are these included in the standard library currently somewhere? And if not, are there plans to include this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is supported by passing [the `dir_fd` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#dir-fd) to various functions in the standard `os` module.  See for example [`os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open):

> Open the file path and set various flags [...]
>
> **This function can support paths relative to directory descriptors with the dir_fd parameter.**

If you want to use high-level file objects such as those returned by the *builtin* [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function, that function's documentation provides example code showing how to do this using the `opener` parameter to that function.  Note that `open()` and `os.open()` are entirely different functions and should not be confused.  Alternatively, you could open the file with `os.open()` and then pass the file descriptor number to [`os.fdopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen) or to `open()`.

It should also be noted that this currently only works on Unix; the portable and future-proof way to check for `dir_fd` support is to write code such as the following:

```
if os.open in os.supports_dir_fd:
    # Use dir_fd.
else:
    # Don't.
```

On the other hand, I'm not entirely sure Windows even allows opening a directory in the first place.  You certainly can't do it with [`_open()`/`_wopen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen), which are documented to fail if "the given path is a directory."  To be safe, I recommend only trying to open the directory after you check for `dir_fd` support.

Comment: Neat. Thanks for the insight!