# FileNotFoundError occured when tried to read multiple text files into single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I tried to read multiple text files from a local directory into one single pandas dataframe. Since original text files come with extra file extension I renamed it, after all, then I tried to read all text files into single dataframe by `read_csv` and `concat` from `pandas`. Problem is, I am able to read single text files with pandas but when I tried to read a list of text files from a local directory into single dataframe, I got following error:

```
folder = 'fakeNewsDatasets[Rada]/fakeNewsDataset/fake'
allfiles=os.listdir(folder)
print(allfiles)

['biz01.txt',
 'biz02.txt',
 'biz03.txt',
 'biz04.txt',
 'biz05.txt',
 'biz06.txt']
```

then I tried to read those text files into single dataframe as follows:

```
dfs=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, header = None, sep = '\n', skip_blank_lines = True) for file in allfiles], axis=1)

*
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'biz02.txt' does not exist:
>   b'biz02.txt'
>   *

I don't understand why this problem occurred because reading a single text file to pandas dataframe works well for me.

```
df = pd.read_csv('biz01.txt', header = None, sep = '\n', skip_blank_lines = True)
df=df.T
df.columns = ['headline', 'text']
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue? how can I fix this error? any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `glob()` it would be easier:

```
import glob
allfiles=glob.glob('C:\\folder1\\*.csv')
```

Else you may have to join the path with `file` while doing `for file in allfiles` when reading the file in `pd.read_csv()`

Comment: I found one error, if text files are located in nested folder and I tried your code, it return empty list, such as my path something like this : `C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\myProj\source\data\fakeNewsDataset\fake`? why and solution?

Comment: @anjy_91 how can I make your solution work if files in subfolders?

Comment: You Mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580716/python-reading-files-from-directory-file-not-found-in-subdirectory-which-is-t if not that should again be a fresh question since here i didn't find you have mentioned about subfolders

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

import os
import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.DataFrame()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(""):
for file in files:
if file.endswith('.txt'):
df = pd.read_csv(root + "/" + file, header=None)
data_set = pd.concat([data_set, df])
data_set.to_csv("/tx.txt", index=False, header=False)